# Handling TreeView MouseMove event in separate thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, events, treeview

{VB.net} I am trying to handle the MouseMove event of a TreeView element in a separate thread, but I don't know how to do that and searching the net did not help a lot.

```
 Private Sub TV_ServerList_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TV_ServerList.MouseMove
    Try

        selNode = DirectCast(TV_ServerList.GetNodeAt(TV_ServerList.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)), TreeNode)

        Dim screenHeight As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height - 220

        If Not oldnode.Name = selNode.Name Then
            frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            Dim cursor_x = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - 800
            Dim cursor_y = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - 10
            If cursor_y > screenHeight Then
                cursor_y = screenHeight
            End If
            frm.Location = New Point(cursor_x, cursor_y)
            Try


                frm.change()

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            frm.Show()
            oldnode = selNode

        ElseIf oldnode.name = "" Then
            frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            Dim cursor_x = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - 800
            Dim cursor_y = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - 10
            frm.Location = New Point(cursor_x, cursor_y)
            Try

                frm.change()

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            frm.Show()
            oldnode = selNode
        Else
            frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
            Dim cursor_x = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X - 800
            Dim cursor_y = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - 10
            frm.Location = New Point(cursor_x, cursor_y)

            oldnode = selNode
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        frm.hide()
    End Try


End Sub
```

I wish to put this code to a separate thread for execution. 
Starting a new thread from inside the `Private Sub TV_ServerList_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TV_ServerList.MouseMove`
is not an option. I wish to start it at the very beginning when Form1 is loaded.

Thx for the help.

Comment: Why is starting a thread from inside the event not an option?

Comment: Since it runs back to the code of Form1 and creates a glitch in viewing something else.

Comment: Sounds more like re-entrancy

Comment: Why do you want to put this code in a different thread? This is a very light code, consuming virtually no resources/time (and thus not really affecting the performance of the GUI thread). Additionally, bear in mind that you cannot perform GUI-related actions from another thread and thus you cannot put this whole code in a different thread; some bits like "frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual" have to remain in the GUI thread.

Comment: It is very light but it is executed many times in a short period causing some TextBox elements to lag since they are showing miliseconds. Setting the FormStartPosition only has to happen once so I can execute it before starting the thread on GUI thread load. The main question is: Is it posible to handle this event in a separate thread?

Comment: This event is associated with a GUI element and thus has to be run in the main thread. But you can put all the contents in a method (methodThread2()), create a second thread (for example, via BackGroundWorker), start it on this event and run methodThread2() from it (you would have also to create another method methodGUI(), which will be dealing with the GUI-related parts). But all this additional work wouldn't change anything (things would actually be slightly slower), as far as you would have to start the second thread every time this event is triggered...

Comment: ... if you have serious performance problems, you should consider to put other parts of your code (not as closely related to GUI as this one) in a second thread. In any case, note that calling many times a very quick function is not what multi-threading is usually for. Multithreading is indicated for situations where the calculations in a given part take too long, what forces a thread to wait for it to finish (what provokes, for example, the form to get frozen when dealing with the GUI). With multi-threading, you allow the slow part(s) to run in the background while you do other things.